# How to plot a thick spiral in MatLab?

Tags: matlab, graph, plot, equation, polar-coordinates

I can plot a regular spiral with

```
w = 0.1;
SAU = 0.1;
r = 0:100;
Phi = 2*pi/w*(1-SAU)*r/500;
```

but how can I change my Phi so that the graph is of a spiral that has some specified thickness rather than just a thin line spiral? Like this (here several spirals are plotted together, by ignore that):
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize the output of your [`polar`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polar.html) call to address and change line properties. In this case we're interested in the `LineWidth` property.

```
w = 0.1;
SAU = 0.1;
r = 0:100;
Phi = 2*pi/w*(1-SAU)*r/500;
h.myplot = polar(Phi, r);
h.myplot.LineWidth = 8; % Adjust as necessary
```

This assumes you have R2014b or newer. If you have an older version, use `set`. See [this blog post](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/graphics_transition/graphics-handles-are-now-objects-not-doubles.html) for more information.

Edit: Per your comment I guess you could do something like:

```
w = 0.1;
SAU = 0.1;
r = 0:100;
Phi = 2*pi/w*(1-SAU)*r/500;

width = 50;
polar(Phi, r, '-b')
hold on
for ii = 2:width
    polar(Phi + (ii*pi)/180, r, '-b');
end
```

For comparison:
[image: plot comparison]

Comment: But that won't actually create extra points tho, would it? For example, if I want all the white area in the graph to be 0 and all the black area to be 1. I guess I'm trying to say I don't want it to be just a visual adjustment, I want that area to physically exist. As in, if you have a flat line segment, don't just blow it up so it looks like a rectangle, but actually write an equation for a rectangle. If that makes sense +.+ ...

Comment: @Solarmew I'm not sure I understand why you'd want to do it that way. As far as I know MATLAB doesn't have this capability, but you could fake it. See my edit for one approach.

Comment: Essentially, I'm trying to bounce a beam of light off a lens which has this pattern machined out of it, so I need to be able to modify the thickness of the trenches to see how much light will get reflected. The beam of light is estimated as a matrix of points. So I need to have this pattern also represented as a matrix.

Comment: @Solarmew if that's the case it's probably easier to use an equation driven curve in one of the more popular CAD programs and offset the sketch to get your trench width. I'm sure there's some matrix transformation that can be done to mimic a change in line width but I don't know what it is.

Comment: I see. That's too bad :( Well, thank you for you help anyways. Is there maybe a way to convert the created image of the spiral into an array of points?